# How to convert awk match to powershell command?

Tags: powershell, awk, kubectl

I am currently running this command on a linux machine to get pods older than 1 day:

```
kubectl get pod | awk 'match($5,/[0-9]+d/) {print $1}'
```

I want to be able to run the same command in Powershell. How could I do it?

`kubectl get pod` output:

```
        NAME       READY     STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE
        pod-name   1/1       Running     0             2h3m
        pod-name2  1/1       Running     0             1d2h
        pod-name3  1/1       Running     0             4d4h
```

`kubectl get pod | awk 'match($5,/[0-9]+d/) {print $1}'` output:

```
    pod-name2
    pod-name3
```

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl get pod` ?

Comment: @Paolo I updated my origin post with the output. Please note that they could be multiple rows similar to pod-name

Comment: The closing quote on the Awk script is missing and the backslashes before the dollar signs is wrong. The script could succinctly be rewritten to just `$5 ~ /[0-9]+d/`

Comment: @tripleee Just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$long_running_pods=(kubectl get pod | Tail -n+2 | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames NAME, READY, STATUS, RESTARTS, AGE | Where-Object {$_.AGE -match "[1-9][0-9]*d[0-9]{1,2}h"})
$long_running_pods.NAME
```

This will give you all pods which have been running for more than one day.

---

Example:

```
$long_running_pods=(echo 'NAME       READY     STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE
pod-name   1/1       Running     0             1d2h
pod-name2  1/1       Running     0             0d0h' | Tail -n+2 | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames NAME, READY, STATUS, RESTARTS, AGE | Where-Object {$_.AGE -match "[1-9][0-9]*d[0-9]{1,2}h"})
$long_running_pods.NAME
```

will print:

```
pod-name
```

Comment: Getting: Tail : The term 'Tail' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: @Oplop98 which powershell version are you using?

Comment: I use version 5.1

Comment: Instead of the tail you can do `select-object -skip 1`.

Comment: @js2010 What does Tail or what you sent do exactly? The script seems to work without it

Comment: Skips the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Awk might be a little more convenient in this case.  You have to prevent the $split array from being spun out in the pipe before where-object.  It turns out I can still reference the $split variable in the foreach-object.

```
'        NAME       READY     STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE
         pod-name   1/1       Running     0             2h3m
         pod-name2  1/1       Running     0             1d2h
         pod-name3  1/1       Running     0             4d4h' | set-content file

get-content file | 
  where-object { $split = -split $_; $split[4] -match '[0-9]+d' } |
  foreach-object { $split[0] }

pod-name2
pod-name3
```